# Solr Write-lock issue

Tags: solr, lucene

Environment: Solr 1.4 on Windows/MS SQL Server

A write lock is getting created whenever I am trying to do a full-import of documents using DIH. Logs say "Creating a connection with the database....." and the process is not going forward (Not getting a database connection). So the indexes are not getting created. Note that no other process is accessing the index and even I restarted my MS SQL Server service. However still I see a write.lock file in my index directory.

What could be the reason for this? Even I have set the flag unlockOnStartup in solrconfig to be true, still the indexing is not happening.

Comment: When you delete the file, does it come back?

Comment: It will be hard to help you without more details. Do you have any relevant logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was resolved. There was some issue with the java update and the microsoft jdbc driver.